# durandal event not working properly

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I am using durandal to pass messages between view models. So i used below code to send message

```
 return (datacontext.getData("Test, testData))
                .then(app.trigger('FireEvent', `dataObsArray`))
                .fail(queryFailed);
```

Then i use below code to retrieve message

```
 app.on('FireEvent').then(function (data) {
            testObsArray(data);
        });
```

But when i put breakpoint in the app.on on this line `testObsArray(data);`
it doesnt stop there. The debugger stops on line `app.on('FireEvent').then(function (data)`

I dont get data. Why is it so? When i pass data to `dataObsArray` , there are 10 records.

I am not sure why i am not getting any data. Where i am wrong? I am really new to Durandal so extremely sorry if i am not able to explain this properly and do let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here;

```
.then(app.trigger('FireEvent', `dataObsArray`))
```

The way that will resolve is to call `app.trigger`, get the result, and pass that as the next step in the chain to `then()`, which is unlikely to be what you want. You need to wrap that in an anonymous function so that `then()` can call it *after* the `dataContext` call.

```
return (datacontext.getData("Test, testData))
                .then(function(data) {
                    app.trigger('FireEvent', data?) //This depends on what getData returns
                })
                .fail(queryFailed);
```

Comment: What if i dont want to pass data returning from datacontext? I tried using function but it still not working.

Comment: What does `getData()` do then? Set something that will be collected by the event listener? If that is the case, using a function should work, and you have another issue if it isn't. Unfortunately I can't say what that is without more information.

Comment: getData just return some data from webapi. actually i have 2 app.trigger like this return (datacontext.getData("Test, testData))
                .then(function() {
                    app.trigger('FireEvent', dataObsArray); app.trigger('FireEvent1',testData);
                })
                .fail(queryFailed);

Comment: If `getData()` returns the `dataObsArray`, then it needs to be the parameter to the `then()` handler. `datacontext.getData("Test, testData)) .then(function(dataObsArray) { app.trigger('FireEvent', dataObsArray)`

Comment: getData returns data and that i pass to obs array called dataObsArray. I get some data in testData from other way and that i want to pass. Hence i tried to use 2 app.trigger statement, one will get data from getData method and other will just get data from other obs array.

Comment: You're going to need to post your code, I'm not sure I understand.